# Makefile won't find *.lib but path is declared

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a plugin example for a software from autodesk.

here is the Makefile

```
##############################################################################
#           Makefile for use by API developers                               #
#                                                                            #
#  NOTE: "vcvarsall amd64" must be run before attempting to compile the API  #
#  examples. Please see the API documentation for information.               #
#                                                                            #
##############################################################################

#
# If the location of the Alias libraries and header files are
# different from $ALIAS_LOCATION, set it here.
#
ALIAS_LOCATION=C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AliasSurface2023.0


CPPEXAMPLES = cppCube.exe

EXAMPLES = $(CPPEXAMPLES)

CC = cl.exe
CPLUSPLUS = cl.exe
LINK = link.exe

INCLUDES = /I. /I"$(ALIAS_LOCATION)\ODS\Common\include" /I"C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" /I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include"

# 
# Dynamic Linking.
#
EXTRA_LFLAGS = /LIBPATH:"$(ALIAS_LOCATION)\lib";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64" /VERBOSE
EXTRA_CFLAGS = 
LFLAGS = /nologo /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB $(EXTRA_LFLAGS) /STACK:0xa00000

#
# Required libraries. 
#
LIBS = libalias_api.lib

STD = kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib \
     advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib \
     odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib comctl32.lib netapi32.lib \
     version.lib ws2_32.lib

CLIBS = $(LIBS) $(STD)

CFLAGS = /nologo /MD $(INCLUDES) $(COPIOUS_OUTPUT) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
CPLUSPLUSFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)

#
# Rules for building.
#
.SUFFIXES: .c .c++ .obj .cpp

.cpp.obj:
    $(CPLUSPLUS) -c $(CPLUSPLUSFLAGS) $*.cpp

.c.obj:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c

#
# Build all the examples.
#
default: $(EXAMPLES)

#
# Copy all the source files for the examples.
#
copy:
    copy "$(ALIAS_LOCATION)\ODS\OpenModel\examples\*.cpp" .
    copy "$(ALIAS_LOCATION)\ODS\OpenModel\examples\*.c" .
    copy "$(ALIAS_LOCATION)\ODS\Common\examples\*.cpp" .
    copy "$(ALIAS_LOCATION)\ODS\Common\examples\*.c" .
    copy "$(ALIAS_LOCATION)\ODS\Common\examples\*.h" .

#
# Clean up.
#
clean:
    del *.obj *.exp *.lib $(EXAMPLES)

#
# Rules for building the executables.

cppCube.exe:            cppCube.obj
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) /out:$@ cppCube.obj $(CLIBS)
```

problem is that when I try to run `nmake`, it doesn't find the file that instead are present in the directories mentioned:

```bash
$ nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.37.32825.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        link.exe /nologo /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AliasSurface2023.0\lib";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64" /STACK:0xa00000 /VERBOSE /out:cppCube.exe cppCube.obj libalias_api.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib  advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib  odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib comctl32.lib netapi32.lib  version.lib ws2_32.lib

Starting pass 1
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libalias_api.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'link.exe /nologo /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AliasSurface2023.0\lib";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64" /STACK:0xa00000 /VERBOSE /out:cppCube.exe cppCube.obj libalias_api.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib  advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib  odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib comctl32.lib netapi32.lib  version.lib ws2_32.lib' : return code '0x49d'
Stop.
```

I run `$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64` getting this message `[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'` .

I have isntalled Visual Studio Tools and running from a Administrator Developer Command Prompt.

is the errror only complaining of 'libalias_api.lib'? or also for kernel32.lib? it is phrased in an ambiguous way.

Here is the guide that I followed:
https://help.autodesk.com/view/ALIAS/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-D9756922-3960-4FC6-AFFC-940A0A5E8C7F

--- UPDATE 1 ---
After installing Windows SDK and still get LINK error

Comment: Why does the title say that "kernel32.lib" is not found while the error message says something about "libalias_api.lib"? Which one is your real problem?

Comment: it is both really, both are present in the two directories indicated in /LIBPATH respectively, but both are said from the error message to not be found. I decided to put kernel32.lib in the title as it is something everybody knows, while libalias_api.lib is very specific to the software I am trying to build a plug-in for, that nobody uses.

Comment: Kernel32.lib should always be in the linker path. If it's not, you likely have some problem with your compiler installation.

Comment: yes, I guess I have to resintall everythig.. any good way to start clean? what's the easiest way to delete everything and start over?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? They are two different products.

Comment: I am trying from Studio Code, but I also installed Visual Studio.. worth to understand how VS works and running the compilation from there?

Comment: is the errror only complaining of 'libalias_api.lib'? or also for kernel32.lib? it is phrase in an ambiguous way

Comment: Have you tried using Visual Studio x64 native command tool? And are you able to build a hello world program using nmake?

Comment: at the moment I resintalled everything wihtout VS, but only VS Build Tools, and I am launching `nmake` from the Developer Command Prompt. But you are right, I will try with a hellowrold `nmake` project and see if the problem is not even related to this specific project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured that the Makefile was just trying to put together two CLI commands.

So I put together the two commands, and after some investigation on how to correct the syntax, I finally managed to compile everything with the following CLI commands:

```bash
cl /c /I “C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AliasSurface2023.0\ODS\Common\include” cppView.cpp /link “C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AliasSurface2023.0\lib”;“C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64”

link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AliasSurface2023.0\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64" /out:cppView.exe cppView.obj libalias_api.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib comctl32.lib netapi32.lib version.lib ws2_32.lib
```

Answer (score 1):

> not sure where to find or run `vcvarsall`

Well, that's the problem right there. That batch file sets the environment variables so that Visual Studio components can find each other. In this case, the linker cannot find the SDK.

The batch file is located inside the Visual Studio install dir. It's likely also accessible via the start menu, and from inside the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: thanks I now run the `vcvarsall` getting this message `[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'`, then I run `nmake` again, but the same error as earlier comes up.

Comment: @user3755529: Well, in addition to vcvarsall to **find** the various components, you also need to **install** the components. Can't find what does not exist. Did you install the current Windows SDK? (or at least some recent version?)

Comment: after installing this https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/ I restart,  rerun the commands and get the same error, I have added to the question the latest attempt.